# How to know number of redefined permission?

Tags: android

I have to determine the application is malware or benign. So, I have to pass six information items (1)permissions, (2)Intent-filter(action), (3)Intent-filter(category),(4)Process Name, (5)Intent-filter(priority), and **(6)Number of redefined permission**. In this case, the first four items are represented as string and the other two are represented by integer value as the proposed method said. The above five items are easy to pass. But I need to know where is the number of redefined permission value? And if it is not in manifest.xml, how to pass this value by coding? If it is not ok,please let me know **what is redefined permission at least**.

Please give me some suggestions. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by redefined permissions. Permissions that you have to request at runtime?

Comment: @DariusL Are permissions and uses-permissions the same?

Comment: I believe the `<permission>` tag is used to declare your own permissions for other apps to use.

Comment: Please let me know how many types of declaring permissions? Like <permissions>, <uses-permissions>, in the other tag permissions ="......"

Comment: Yes, Can this <permission> tag be redefined permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the detailed document : [App Manifest | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: But, I am not actually expert at this. I do well known about android permissions and requested permission but number of redefined permission is new for me. Please give me more detail. Thank again.

Comment: If it is not in android manifest.xml, how to pass this value by code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The method said that number of redefined permission is represented by integer. I don't really know where to find.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I don't quite understand to redefine the permission this meaning.
I am also a beginner.